# Segmentation fault after updating eccodes for python

Tags: python-3.x, cfgrib, eccodes

I updated my eccodes-library from 2.17.0 to 2.23.0 with the help of the following gist: https://gist.github.com/MHBalsmeier/a01ad4e07ecf467c90fad2ac7719844a

After updating the following example crashes, when using eccodes in version higher than 2.17.0:

```
from cfgrib.xarray_store import open_dataset as od
ds = od('20220420.grib2', backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveGround', 'level': 2}})
```

returns:

```
segmentation fault
```

I noticed that the problem does not occure when running eccodes version 2.17.0 instead of version 2.23.0 or another version higher than 2.17.0. Installation of version 2.23.0 was successfull, because `python3 -m eccodes selfcheck` returns

```
Found: ecCodes v2.23.0.
Your system is ready.
```

Do you have same problems and how did you solve it?

Comment: I experienced similar issues with the latest version of eccodes + cfgrib. But I receive no error message.